# Hough Intersection points

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition, hough-transform, shape-recognition

I made a hough transform for car plate recognition. I found some vertical and horizontal lines. I need to make an algorithm such that it will choose the right rectangle shape.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgam6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAJaI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CfC3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nWPa.png)

I tried to control it with edge map so I can only draw with pixel value 255 but couldnt figure it out.

```
def extract_hough_lines( local_maximas,diag_lenx,edges,row,col):

    
    lines = []
    for theta_ind, rho_ind in zip(local_maximas[0], local_maximas[1]):
        
        x1,y1,x2,y2=0,0,0,0
        rho =int(round(rho_ind - diag_lenx)) 
        theta = np.deg2rad(theta_ind)
        x0, y0 = 0,0
        cos_t, sin_t = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
        
        if theta_ind==0:
            # dogru dik
            x0, y0 = rho, 0

        elif theta_ind==90:
            # dogru paralel
            x0, y0 = 0, rho
        else:
            x0 =int(round(cos_t * rho)) 
            y0 =int(round(sin_t * rho))  
            
        x1 = int(round(x0 + 1000 * (-sin_t)))
        y1 = int(round(y0 + 1000 * (cos_t)))
        x2 = int(round(x0 - 1000 * (-sin_t)))
        y2 = int(round(y0 - 1000 * (cos_t)))
        

        
            
        lines.append((theta, rho, (x1, y1), (x2, y2)))

    return lines
```

Comment: Is it really that difficult to "enter image description here"? Don't you think that having that 4 times in your post makes it look rather low-quality? Also, provide a proper [mcve].